# Как визуализировать генетический алгоритм движения к цели?

Tags: графика, алгоритм, c++

Задача: есть цель(круг), к которой за определенное количество шагов особи-круги либо достигают, либо не достигают. Достижение с помощью генетического алгоритма.
Сам алгоритм я написал, все уже вроде готово. Но с визуализацией мне дается тяжело. Осталось только в цикле шагов рисовать объекты (как движение или хотя бы новые как на картинке). Должно получиться примерно такое движение(или посекундное рисование)(см. картинку).

По коду: координаты х,y - это H[i].genes[0] и H[i].genes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HP75.jpg) соответственно

Вот код:

```
// moveC.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//#include <gl/glut.h"
#include <math.h>
#include<glut.h>

GLint Width = 512, Height = 512;

//--------------------------------
const int N = 3;
const int n = 4;
float L = 400;
float h = 1;

//--------------------------------
class hromos {
 public:
    float genes[n];
};

//--------------------------------
hromos *H;

//--------------------------------
hromos mutation(hromos hr)
{
    if (hr.genes[0] < L / 2)
        hr.genes[0] += hr.genes[2]; //x
    if (hr.genes[0] > L / 2)
        hr.genes[0] -= hr.genes[2]; //x
    hr.genes[1] += hr.genes[3]; //y
    hr.genes[3] += h;   //hy

    return hr;
}

//--------------------------------
void crossover_and_mutation()
{
    int g1, g2;
    float c;
    hromos *ocross;
    ocross = new hromos[N];
    hromos *mas;
    mas = new hromos[3 * N];
    //выбор 2х особей 
    int io1, io2;
    //разные индексы
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; ++i) {
        do
            io1 = rand();
        while (io1 >= N && io1 >= n);
        io2 = io1;
        while (io2 = io1 && io2 >= n)
            io2 = rand();

        //копируем выбранные особи в отдельный массив для кроссинговера
        ocross[i] = H[io1];
        ocross[i + 1] = H[io2];
        //выбираем 2 случайных гена для обмена
        do
            g1 = rand();
        while (g1 >= N && g1 >= n);
        g2 = g1;
        while (g2 = g1 && g2 >= n)
            g2 = rand();
        //обмен первыми генами
        c = ocross[i].genes[g1];
        ocross[i].genes[g1] = ocross[i + 1].genes[g1];
        ocross[i + 1].genes[g1] = c;
        //обмен вторыми генами
        c = ocross[i].genes[g2];
        ocross[i].genes[g2] = ocross[i + 1].genes[g2];
        ocross[i + 1].genes[g2] = c;
        //мутация потомков
        ocross[i] = mutation(ocross[i]);
        ocross[i + 1] = mutation(ocross[i + 1]);
    }
    //помещаем всех особей(поп.+потомки) в 1 массив для сортировки
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        mas[i] = H[i];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = N; i < (N + N); ++i) {
        mas[i] = ocross[k];
        k++;
    }
    //сортируем по лучшим показателям x,y по убыванию
    hromos d;
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + N + N); ++i)
        for (int j = i; j < (N + N + N); ++j) {
            if ((mas[i].genes[0] + mas[i].genes[1]) <
                (mas[j].genes[0] + mas[j].genes[1])) {
                d = mas[i];
                mas[i] = mas[j];
                mas[j] = d;
            }
        }
    //из mas создаем новую популяци из лучших особей
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        H[i] = mas[i];
    //рисуем особей

    //высвобождаем память
    delete[]ocross;
}

//--------------------------------
int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int steps;
    printf("\nInput count of steps: ");
    scanf("%d", &steps);
    H = new hromos[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            H[i].genes[j] = rand();
    //на каждом шаге должна рисоваться новая популяция
    for (int step = 1; step < steps; ++step) {
        crossover_and_mutation();
        //здесь надо нарисовать получившуюся новую популяцию H[i]
    }
}
```

Изображение:

[image]

Comment: >Здесь код как-то очень криво вставляется, и тэгов специальных нет,

Есть специальная магическая кнопка, на которой нарисовано 10101

Comment: сервисы наподобие [Pastie](pastie.org/) тоже можно использовать, чтобы не загромождать вопрос большим листингом кода

Comment: @okwell5, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: >Сервисы наподобие Pastie тоже можно использовать, чтобы не загромождать вопрос большим листингом кода.

 На них не все будут заходить. Лучше сделать поддержку спойлеров.

Answer (score 1):

Основы работы с графикой смотрите здесь

- [Учебное пособие по OpenGL](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/opengl/ogltutor.xml)
- [Графическая библиотека OpenGL](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/opengl/ogltut2.xml).

Вам потребуется функция рисования круга. В качестве стартовой точки можно взять такую

```
void drawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, int segments)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        for (int i = 0; i <= segments; ++i) {
            float t = 2*M_PI*i/segments
            glVertex2f(x + sin(t)*radius, y + cos(t)*radius);
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

Отрисовывая ее по времени или по координатам в зависимости от значения хромосом, вы получите динамику развития популяций.